# Conditional Self Joins

Tags: sql, db2, self-join

Suppose I have data like this in a table :

```
Trade Id | Source
----------------- 
x        | LCH      
x        | Commodore  
y        | LCH          
z        | Commodore
```

I would like an output like this :

```
x | LCH           
y | LCH           
z | Commodore
```

Meaning if there is any "LCH" entry for a given trade id, that would take the precedence.

I could have done this easily in Java or any other programming language by getting the basic results after joining the tables and then filter it using map etc. but due to performance reasons we would like to do this using a query at the first place.

Could you please have a look and let me know if there is any solution in SQL.

Comment: What is the DBMS flavour you use?

Comment: Are there only two values `LCH` and `Commodore`? if not then can you please update your sample data and expected output with it...  ---Do you want one row for each `Trade_id` and corresponding `source` will follow your rule? OR --- do want to exclude those rows from result set for which there is an entry exists with `LCH`?

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar its DB2

Answer (score 2):

We have to follow the Divide and Conquer logic.

Let's first display all the `trade_id`'s with `source = 'LCH'`

```
SELECT Trade_id,Source
FROM your_table
WHERE Source='LCH'
```

Now, we have to pull the other trade_id's that doesn't have `LCH` source! Here I am using `NOT EXISTS` for the same.

```
SELECT Trade_id,Source
FROM your_table a
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (SELECT 'X' FROM your_table b
  WHERE a.Trade_id = b.Trade_id
    AND b.Source = 'LCH')
```

Now that we have extracted all the rows we wanted, So we do `UNION` (Set operation) of both resultsets.

```
SELECT Trade_id,Source
FROM your_table
WHERE Source='LCH'
UNION ALL
SELECT Trade_id,Source
FROM your_table a
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (SELECT 'X' FROM your_table b
  WHERE a.Trade_id = b.Trade_id
    AND b.Source = 'LCH')
```

Comment: Avoid code only answers. Add some description about your solution.

Comment: This SQL is self descriptive. And still adding a description to a SQL would take a lot of text. You can widely see so many answers like this! And you can also see my answer history for any description based posts...

Comment: From [Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques) - While a code-only answer get the person who asked the question past whatever hurdle they might be facing, it doesn't do them or future visitors much good in the long run.

We've always touted that we aren't a code factory. We are the people who teach others to fish. Code-only answers only feed a person for a day.

Comment: @ughai agreed. Added as much as details.

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar tx a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a task for a Windowed Aggregate Function, no need for a join:

```
SELECT Trade_id, Source
FROM
 (
   SELECT Trade_id, Source,
      ROW_NUMBER() 
      OVER (PARTITION BY Trade_id
            ODER BY CASE WHEN Source = 'LCH' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS rn
   FROM your_table
 ) AS dt
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select * from table where source = 'LCH'
Union 
select * from table where source <> 'LCH' and trade_id not in (select * from table where source = 'LCH'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [Trade Id],Source
FROM table1
WHERE Source = 'LCH'
Union
SELECT [Trade Id],Source
FROM table1
WHERE Source<> 'LCH'
AND [Trade Id] NOT IN (SELECT [Trade Id] FROM table1 WHERE Source= 'LCH')
```